# Why is there no min/max statistic for String columns in Hive/Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I see a number of different situations where a min/max statistic on string columns could really be used to the benefit of predicate pushdown for querying these tables. But you can see in the link [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-LogicalPlan-DescribeColumnCommand.html) that these are not supported by spark and from my understanding hive either.

Why is this the case?

Will this be supported at some point of time in the future?